# What to do about the tag [office-addins]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

For those who didn't know, Microsoft is changing the name "Apps for Office" to "Office Add-ins" (take a look at the note [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220060.aspx)). That however seems to raise some confusion because there is another "Office Add-ins" Microsoft has that is for developing application level Extensions using C# or VB.Net via VSTO:

[image: VSTO Add-in]

I feel that when this rename is complete, it will also have a confusing effect on SO. Currently the tag [office-addins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-addins) says:

> Microsoft Visual Studio provides project templates you can use to create application-level add-ins for Microsoft Office 2010 and Office 2007. You can use add-ins to automate Office, extend Office features, or customize the Office user interface.

Now, when "Apps for Office" becomes "Office Add-ins", how will users tag VSTO Add-ins v.s. Web App Add-ins? Will we have to split the tag?

Comment: Why can't they tag them the same. That MS gives them the same name probably tells what their intentions are.